# recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 32

Tags: android, gradle

who can help me fix this warning " We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 32

This Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31

This warning can be suppressed by adding
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 32
"
How to fix it?

thanks All

Comment: The message pretty much explains itself. It is not an error. It is just a recommendation. You are not supposed to "fix" it. You can decide whether or not to follow the recommendation. That's all.

Comment: I am also experiencing this warning, but this is just a warning and this is how Google works with their messed up library syncing.

Answer (score 4):

With upcoming versions of AGP, this should be solved but till then you can follow the quick suppression fix given there in the warning:
**"This warning can be suppressed by adding android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32 to this project's gradle.properties"**

**EDIT**:-

I checked today and there's now no need to suppress the warning.

AGP Version: 7.2.0-alpha07

Gradle Version: 7.4-rc-1

Comment: The other way is to downgrade the SDK to 31 but I think it's not necessary.

Comment: you help me alot